# How to disable Username-input field (StEntry) Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, themes, gdm

Is it possible to hide or disable the input-field for `Username` in the logon screen on Ubuntu 20.04 - making it "impossible" to type into the field for a period of time? Reason for this is to make it clear for the student (along with a background image) that the machine is still being configured.
(See picture below for reference)

Ubuntu 20.04 Login screen
[image: Ubuntu 20.04 Login screen]

I think it has something to do with the `gdm3.css` in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresoure`.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you need to explain why this is necessary. [Edit] accordingly.

Comment: Is the additional comment sufficient?